# include all includes in recursive relationship - strapi

Tags: bookshelf.js, strapi

I have a collection type `component` which includes a set of components. In a tree structure, They can have multiple components too. This include-depth can be any number.

```
component : {
    components []
    name:""
}
```

When I call the API, I want to return the requested component with including all includes in the structure whatever they are nested. But currently, I get only one nested level includes. How can I achieve my requirement?

I cannot use :

```
strapi.query('component').find(id,[
      'components.components.....'
    ])
```

because I don't know the actual depth and I want to include name.

Comment: Did you try using [model.find().populate('components')](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-alpha.x/guides/models.html#relations)?

Comment: To recursively populate you may need to add the afterFetch hook to the model and call the populate() method there too.

Comment: Both cases it says *.populate is not a function